# CSS leading dots with transparent BG

Tags: css

I'm looking for a way to create leading dots after a text element. I need something that has a transparent background around the h1 element. Here is was my solutions needs to look like: http://www.redhatsociety.com/sites/all/themes/red_hat_society/images/partners/sample.png

and here is what I have right now that is not working: http://redhatsociety.com/rhs-hoot-day/prizes

Anyone know of a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a pseudo-element like this.

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/DsEma)

```css
h2 {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width:80% /* not required */

}

h2 span {
  display: inline-block;
  width:50%;
}

h2:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  border: 3px red;
  border-style:dashed;
  width: 9999px;   /* some huge width */
}
```

```html
<h2>
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe error ea nam corporis hic libero culpa excepturi perspiciatis, necessitatibus</span>
</h2>
```

Comment: Glad to help. If you wish, upvote &/or mark as solved.